# Question on finding the variance

Tags: self-study, variance, arithmetic

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Nde.png)

For part B, I previously had 2.07 which is incorrect but why?! I literally followed the formula and I encountered a similar problem on the internet that did the exact same thing I did done below:

```
4(0-2.31)^2 + 7(1-2.31)^2 + 13(2-2.31)^2 + 11(3-2.31)^2 + 3(4-2.31)^2 + 1(5-2.31)^2 + 2(6-2.31)^2 / 41 -1
```

Ignore 21.47 but someone assist me what am I doing wrong here, please.

Comment: Where at the end you write `.../41 -1` you probably meant `.../(41-1)`.  You also need to parenthesize the entire numerator.

Comment: That's still going to give me 2.07

Comment: It's possible you are being asked about a *population* rather than a sample--it's unclear from your post.  In that case you would divide by $41$ instead of $40$ and the answer would be $2.02.$

Answer (score 0):

[image: R calculation]
Not sure where you got 21.47.

I think you might be doing #cars-1 (which is 40) in the denominator instead of #flaws/car - 1 (which is 6)?

I tried your numbers out in R and attached the output.

I had 5.21

Comment: You might need to consider the weights (number of cars) to get it right.